# Create TableRows using data from a TreeMap android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, treemap, tablerow

Im trying to make a loop to iterate through the TreeMap, get its values and display them in a TableRow but its not working, the main problem im having is that I need to insert 7 textviews in a tablerow and then create another tablerow with another 7 textviews and so on, I also tried to use a for loop with the values from an ArrayList but I cant figure out how to change the behaviour of the loop everytime 7 textviews have been added.

heres the code for the treemap:

```
 public void mapTest()
{
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego"});
    data.put("2", new Object[] {"Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena"});

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();

    for (String key : keyset)
    {
        Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
        for (Object obj : objArr)
        {
            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
            newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView newText = new TextView(this);
            newText.setText((String)obj);
            newText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newRow.addView(newText);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code for the for loop with the arraylist:

```
public void addItemsTable(){
    addToPrueba();
    // reference the table layout
    TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.Employees);

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
    newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for(int i = 0; i<prueba.size(); i++) {
        TextView newText = new TextView(this);
        newText.setText(prueba.get(i));
        newText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newRow.addView(newText);
    }

    tbl.addView(newRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, this is the code that worked

```
    public void mapPrueba()
{
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego","Diego"});
    data.put("2", new Object[] {"Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena","Barrena"});

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();

    TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.Employees);

    for (String key : keyset)
    {
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
        for (Object obj : objArr)
        {
            TextView newText = new TextView(this);
            newText.setText((String)obj);
            newText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newRow.addView(newText);
        }
        tbl.addView(newRow);
    }
}
```

hope someone find this useful !